# Is there a performance penalty of using a grid with only one combination in spark ML

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using spark 1.6.0. and I have 2 similar methods : one calling a single `Predictor` and another using a `Grid` to call the same `Predictor`. Unfortunately, I have some code duplications.

So, I'd like to refactor and I was thinking of using a Grid for both cases. So the question is there a performance penalty of using a grid when you have only one combination ?